# Duvida em HQL ao fazer função Sum

Tags: sql, hql

Tenho uma duvida em hql.

Meu sistema possui 3 tabelas tabela1 e  tabela 2 e tabela 3

tabela 3 armazena os registros de chave primaria da tabela1 e da tabela2 para fazer os relacionamentos.

A tabela 1 pode conter N associações com a tabela 2 mas a tabela 2 só pode pertencer a 1 registro da tabela 1;

Quero fazer um select que me retorne a soma de um campo que armazena um inteiro, uma data da tabela2 e o id da  tabela1.

Quando executo este Hql ele só funciona corretamente se "b.campo" for único caso contrario ele não executa a função sum corretamente pois no select.

```
select distinct a.id,sum(b.valor) ,b.campo from entidade1 a inner join entidade2 b;
```

Eu sei que isso ocorre pois são retornados todos os valores diferentes na hora de  fazer  o sum, mas não sei como corrigir.
Tem algum modo?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, para fazer a soma `sum()` você precisa agrupar `group by`.

Acho que sua query seria assim:

```
select a.id,sum(b.valor) ,b.campo from entidade1 a inner join entidade2 b GROUP BY a.id, b.campo
```

Com a clausula `GROUP BY` você não precisa do `distinct`.

Segue a documentação do `Hibernate`:

> https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/pt-BR/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping